# A state mutation was detected inside a dispatch

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I am trying to update my react state but getting above error. Followed as many documentation as I can but, nothing seems to be working.

I have a drag and drop panel (reorder of elements in same panel), on drag of element I am getting dragged index and on drop I am getting hover index (on which I will be dropping the element).

what I want to achieve is on drop, I want to update some attributes of element which I am dragging eg. "dbc" attribute of dragged element or replace entire object. I am using immutability-helper. Below is my code snippet

```
my_state = [{abc:11, bcd:23, dbc: 34}, {abc:12, bcd:33, dbc: 36}, {abc:13, bcd:35, dbc: 37}]
```

suppose I am dragging object at index 0 on object at index 2, after modifying dragged object my state should look like

```
 [{abc:12, bcd:33, dbc: 36}, {abc:13, bcd:35, dbc: 37}, {abc:11, bcd:23, dbc: 39}]
```

Implementation 1:

```
    data = update(my_state, {
      $splice: [
        [action.dragIndex, 1],
        [action.hoverIndex, 0, dragCard], // dragCard is original object with no change
      ],
    });
    data = update(data, {
      [action.hoverIndex]: { $merge: { ...tempDragCard } }, // updated object
    });
```

Implementation 2:

```
    data = update(my_state, {
      $splice: [
        [action.dragIndex, 1],
        [action.hoverIndex, 0, tempDragCard], // passing modified object
      ],
    });
```

In both the cases I am getting error

Comment: Where are you getting the `update` function from? I am assuming that `$splice` and `$merge` are jQuery, right? Could you create a [CodeSandbox](https://codesandbox.io/) with a minimal working example that shows your issue? The question is not complete enough to answer.

Comment: it is comming from  "immutability-helper" library